# GPD Win alternatives for hand-held Steam gaming?

Tags: gaming, portable, steam

I recently learned by chance about the [GPD Win](http://www.google.com/search?q=gpd+win&&tbm=isch), a "laptop fitting in your pocket".

[image]

I had been looking for a portable machine with joystick/controllers that I could take on a crowded metro, and that could allow me to play some of the game titles of my Steam collection, and GPD Win seems to be an excellent candidate.
However, this [Reddit forum](http://www.reddit.com/r/gpdwin/) seems to suggest that the machine requires a number of tweaks to be taken the most of.

Are there more user-friendly similar products, in the sense that they do not require customizations to provide the best "nomad Steam gaming" experience?

Comment: First of all, what do you define as "portable?"  I'm running my steam games, as well as battle.net, and origin games on my gaming laptop, which while being a 15" ~$800 system, I consider to be portable.........not as portable as, say, an Nvidia Shield.  And definitely not "luggable" as defined by bulky mobile 80s computer systems like the Osbourne.

Comment: I mean mainly, small enough to play in a crowded metro, and with joysticks / controllers to play comfortably.

Comment: I believe this discussion can help https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoNX/comments/559kyg/nx_vs_pgs_vs_smach_z_vs_gpd_win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no really alternative to GPD Win currently as a handheld Steam-available gaming device (except... GPD Win 2 probably).
I ended up getting the GPD Win ; I played a bit more on it recently (after having applied the recommended tweaks) and like it a lot.